# Float compile-time calculation not happening?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

A little test program:

```
#include <iostream>


const float TEST_FLOAT = 1/60;

const float TEST_A = 1;
const float TEST_B = 60;
const float TEST_C = TEST_A / TEST_B;

int main()
{
 std::cout << TEST_FLOAT << std::endl;
 std::cout << TEST_C << std::endl;

 std::cin.ignore();
 return 0;
}
```

Result :

```
0
0.0166667
```

Tested on Visual Studio 2008 & 2010.

1. I worked on other compilers that, if I remember well, made the first result like the second result. Now my memory could be wrong, but shouldn't TEST_FLOAT have the same value than TEST_C? If not, why?
2. Is TEST_C value resolved at compile time or at runtime? I always assumed the former but now that I see those results I have some doubts...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In

```
1/60
```

Both of the operands are integers, so integer arithmetic is performed.  To perform floating point arithmetic, at least one of the operands needs to have a floating point type.  For example, any of the following would perform floating point division:

```
1.0/60
1.0/60.0
1/60.0
```

(You might choose to use `1.0f` instead, to avoid any precision reduction warnings; `1.0` has type `double`, while `1.0f` has type `float`)

> Shouldn't `TEST_FLOAT` have the same value than `TEST_C`?

In the `TEST_FLOAT` case, integer division is performed and then the result of the integer division is converted to `float` in the assignment.

In the `TEST_C` case, the integer literals `1` and `60` are converted to `float` when they are assigned to `TEST_A` and `TEST_B`; then floating-point division is performed on those floats and the result is assigned to `TEST_C`.

> Is `TEST_C` value resolved at compile time or at runtime?

It depends on the compiler; either method would be standards-conforming.

Comment: Argh! I knew I missed something obvious! Thanks!